# ASP .NET MVC Form Submit does not trigger Controller Action Method a second time.

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that has a form with multiple drop-downs and a submit button. The submit action calls the Controller Action Method decorated with HttpPost. When I run the app, the page loads fine and the submit works perfectly the first time. If I navigate out of the page and back to it and try the Submit, it does not hit the Action method at all - but loads the page with the previous values.

My View

```
        <h4>Filters</h4>
        <b>Season         </b>
        <br />
        @Html.DropDownList("SeasonTables", ViewBag.Seasons as SelectList, "...Select Season...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "cmbSeason", style = "width:250px;" })
        <br />
        <br />
        <b>Product Group  </b>
        <br />
        @Html.DropDownList("ProductGrpTable", ViewBag.ProductGrp as SelectList, "...Select Product Grp...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "cmbProductGrp", style = "width:250px;" })
        <br />
        <br />
        <b>Delivery Group </b>
        <br />
        @Html.DropDownList("DeliveryGrpTable", ViewBag.ProductDelGrp as SelectList, "...Select Delivery Grp...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "cmbDeliveryGrp", style = "width:250px;" })
        <br />
        <br />
        <b>Division       </b>
        <br />
        @Html.DropDownList("DivisionTable", ViewBag.DivisionList as SelectList, "...Select Division...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "cmbDivision", style = "width:250px;" })
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </p>


    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Index(FormCollection filterData)
    {

        Session.Remove("filterData");

        LSBusinessObject.Filter filter = new LSBusinessObject.Filter();
        filter.Season = filterData["SeasonTables"];
        filter.ProductGp = filterData["ProductGrpTable"];
        filter.ProductDelGp = filterData["DeliveryGrpTable"];
        filter.Division = filterData["DivisionTable"];


        Session["filterData"] = filter;
        lsBusinessLayer.RunSSIS(filter.Season, filter.ProductGp, filter.ProductDelGp, filter.Division);
        //persist the values
        var seasonListData = from s in lsBusinessLayer.Seasons
                             orderby s.season descending
                             select new
                             {
                                 seasonname = s.season,
                                 seasonID = s.seasonID
                             };

        SelectList seasonList = new SelectList(seasonListData, "seasonname", "seasonname", filter.Season);
        ViewBag.Seasons = seasonList;

        var ProductGpListData = from pg in lsBusinessLayer.ProdGrps
                                orderby pg.Product_Group_Name
                                select new
                                {
                                    pgID = pg.Product_Group_ID,
                                    pgName = pg.Product_Group_Name
                                };
        SelectList pgList = new SelectList(ProductGpListData, "pgName", "pgName", filter.ProductGp);
        ViewBag.ProductGrp = pgList;


        var ProductDelGpListData = from pg in lsBusinessLayer.ProdDelGrps
                                   orderby pg.Product_Delivery_Group_Name
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       pgID = pg.Product_Delivery_Group_ID,
                                       pgName = pg.Product_Delivery_Group_Name
                                   };
        SelectList pgDelList = new SelectList(ProductDelGpListData, "pgName", "pgName", filter.ProductDelGp);
        ViewBag.ProductDelGrp = pgDelList;


        var DivisionListData = from pg in lsBusinessLayer.Divisions
                               orderby pg.Product_Division_Name
                               select new
                               {
                                   pgID = pg.Product_Division_ID,
                                   pgName = pg.Product_Division_Name
                               };
        SelectList divList = new SelectList(DivisionListData, "pgName", "pgName", filter.Division);
        ViewBag.DivisionList = divList;


        Session["UpdateResult"] = "";
        Session["ShowAll"] = "false";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "LScontrol", new { filterData = filter });
    }
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by re-writing the form definition as follows:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "FilterForm" }))
```

{

```
            <h4>Filters</h4>
            <b>Season         </b>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownList("SeasonTables", ViewBag.Seasons as SelectList, "...Select Season...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "cmbSeason", style = "width:250px;" })
            <br />
            <br />
            <b>Product Group  </b>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownList("ProductGrpTable", ViewBag.ProductGrp as SelectList, "...Select Product Grp...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "cmbProductGrp", style = "width:250px;" })
            <br />
            <br />
            <b>Delivery Group </b>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownList("DeliveryGrpTable", ViewBag.ProductDelGrp as SelectList, "...Select Delivery Grp...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "cmbDeliveryGrp", style = "width:250px;" })
            <br />
            <br />
            <b>Division       </b>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownList("DivisionTable", ViewBag.DivisionList as SelectList, "...Select Division...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "cmbDivision", style = "width:250px;" })
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </p>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I admit this is a shot in the dark, but try adding the [NoCache] decorator above
[HttpPost] in your controller.

Comment: Hi - Thanks! But I dont see a NoCache decorator at all! Is it the OutputCache decorator?

Comment: I see you found [NoCache], sorry it didn't work for you.  It was admittedly just one thing to try.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I am still trying to figure this out :)